# css/html buttons link not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, ref

I have seen this question a lot in your forums but, all the answers and even the issues are far more advanced that my knowledge.
I have just started learning html and css, so I came across this page:
[HTML CSS - Responsive buttons (grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073796/html-css-responsive-buttons-grid)
I liked the design so I decided to use it.
Here is the problem: I am running Wamp64. Running a localhost server and database.
However, I want the localhost/index.html page to give me the choice of going to different pages in the localhost using the buttons mentioned above. For example. I click "test 01" and it would take me to "http://localhost/test01", which in turn is connected to a different database. I clik on Test 2, and it would go to the test02 directory in localhost, connected to database test02, and so on.
Using the code above I changed the href to my address (see below), but when I click them, nothing happens:

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" >
<div class="middle">
    <center>

    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="http://localhost/test01">Test 1</a>
    </button> 
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="http://localhost/test02/index.php">Test 2</a>
    </button> 
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="309.html">309</a>
    </button> 
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="304.html">304</a>
    </button>
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="307.html">307</a>
    </button>
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="310.html">310</a>
    </button> 
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="311.html">311</a>
    </button> 
    <button type="button3" class="button3">
    <a href="312.html">312</a>
    </button>
  </center>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.button {
height: 40px;
width: 130px;
margin-bottom: 3%;
background-color: #7C8082;
font-size: 100%;
color: white;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #ffffff;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: #474240;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}   

.button1 {
height: 40px;
width: 70px;
background-color: #7C8082;
font-size: 100%;
color: white;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-top:5px;
}
 .button1:hover {
background-color: #474240;
}

.button3 {
height: 80px;
width: 30%;
background-color: #7C8082;
font-size: 200%;
color: white;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-top:10px;
}

.button3:hover {
background-color: #474240;
}
```

I have tried renaming the links, change the href to action OnClick, even the straight html of 'form method="link" action="http://localhost/test01/index.php> , but the only thing that happens is that, the button reacts to my click but doesn't redirect me.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Stack Overflow is not a forum. 2) It is invalid to nest hyperlinks inside of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it,

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" >
<div class="middle">
    <center>

      <a href="304.html" class ="button3"  >304</a>
      <a href="309.html" class ="button3" > 309</a>
    </center>
</div>
```

did it works ?

Comment: This one did the trick with a little distortion on the CSS formatting. Plox panda's answer  was right as well but Panda's solution really strips all of the css out of it. Im reaing in w3 for the button links as Jeroen suggested. Now its just a word wrapped around a smaller button, but I will try to play with it. If there are more suggestions, I will be happy to hear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `<a href="307.html">307</a>` only the "309" is the clickable link to the webpages and the buttons are basically doing nothing at all.

you can apply a button like style to these links by putting the class name in your links

You can try this below but you may need to update the css to your liking =\

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<header id="header">

<div class="middle">
    <center>

    <a href="http://localhost/test01" class="button3">Test 1</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/test02/index.php" class="button3">Test 2</a>
    <a href="309.html" class="button3">309</a>
    <a href="304.html" class="button3">304</a>
    <a href="307.html" class="button3">307</a>
    <a href="310.html" class="button3">310</a>
    <a href="311.html" class="button3">311</a>
    <a href="312.html" class="button3">312</a>
  </center>
</div>  
</html>
```

Comment: @leinad23ec i've realised the reason my Css didnt work for you is because i had 
`<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

instead of

`<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Whoops!

Comment: Ha!! I was able to fix with the style intact, I did    <a href="http://localhost/tes01" class="button3">test 01</a>    and the css remains intact basically. Thank you!!

Comment: @leinad23ec no problem glad to help :)!

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to place an `a-tag` between a `button-tag`. Its either a button or a link.

Check [HTML button Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) on w3schools for more info.

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Check [HTML a Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) on w3schools for more info.

```html
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```